# How to write a filter to remove a form field (WordPress)

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I want to remove a form field. How do I write a filter hook to remove it?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwoRa.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be a bit more explicit on your post : is it a plugin ? Which one ?

One solution could be to hide it by css. I'm supposing your `data-handler-id` is unique, so you could use it to hide this field like that :

```
[data-handler-id="job_extra_fast_delivery_price"] {
    display: none;
}
```